# What does "light" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

What does light mean here?

"The conduct of Saint John shows him too, to have been, according to the light
that was in him, of a mild and praiseworthy character"

Answer (score 1):

Given the context, I imagine that "light" refers to the characters personality.

More specifically, I would say that it refers to **the goodness in him**.

Additionally you could also say that the "light" is referring to his **moral compass**